# How to get the geofence from Google Map API?

Tags: dictionary

When you type, e.g., "UC Berkeley" into Google map, it shows this:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/University+of+California,+Berkeley
Where the campus is shown in a different and yellowish color. 
Apparently Google distinguishes campus from non-campus. 
I wonder is there any way I can get the geofence using Map API?
Googling this question returns overwhelming results on how to 
create geofence, not on how to get geofence. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Google Maps API and unfortunately I'm almost sure that it's not possible. I think Google define the marker color contrasting it with their database.

Then, the best option is managing it yourself, sorry.